# maven buid on jenkins fails trying to download maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5

Tags: jenkins, maven-3

I have Jenkins installed on a vagrant virtual machine.
Trying to run a simple build with a clean install maven goal, it seems that it cannot download maven artifacts from maven central repo.

```
[INFO] Downloading: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven

/plugins/maven-clean-plugin/2.5/maven-clean-plugin-2.5.pom
[BFA] Scanning build for known causes...
[BFA] No failure causes found
[BFA] Done. 0s
Notifying upstream projects of job completion
Join notifier requires a CauseAction
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 14.883 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2015-12-23T10:56:33+01:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 8M/20M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] **Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:pom:2.5 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): java.security.ProviderException: java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException** -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginResolutionException: Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:jar:2.5
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.resolve(DefaultPluginDependenciesResolver.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getPluginDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:179)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.internal.DefaultMavenPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultMavenPluginManager.java:284)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.getMojoDescriptor(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:241)
    at..... 
[...]
......sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.processMessage(ClientHandshaker.java:278)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.processLoop(Handshaker.java:913)
    at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.process_record(Handshaker.java:849)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(SSLSocketImpl.java:1035)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1344)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(SSLSocketImpl.java:1371)
    ... 71 more
Caused by: **java.security.InvalidAlgorithmParameterException**
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateECKeyPair(Native Method)
    at sun.security.ec.ECKeyPairGenerator.generateKeyPair(ECKeyPairGenerator.java:126)
    ... 80 more
```

It seems that I'm not providing the proper credentials, but I have no idea what credential could be referring to.

Connection to my git repo is ok, using the provided user/pwd based credentials. So this cannot be the reason.

Maven 3.3.9

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is your Jenkins behind a company proxy or somehting?

Comment: No proxy.
settings.xml is the one by default, with no proxy configurations. Just in the same way than my local maven instalation, where mvn clean install works fine.
This Jenkins installation is within a Virtual Box, and settings.xml there is by default as well, with no proxy configs.

Comment: Anyway it seems like a connection issue but I can just guess. There seems to be something in between your Jenkins and "the internet" that breaks the SSL connection. Maybe there is something wrong with the Virtual Box network adapter? Or do you have a proxy that is configured system wide on your local machine?

Comment: While the environment is being installed, vagrant downloads several pluggins like puppet, git, junit and many more. So virtual machine has access to the internet.

Comment: Okay, strange... Then I'm out of ideas. Sorry!

Comment: Have you configured somehow in the jvm `$JAVA_HOME/jre/lib/security/java.security`?

Comment: Thanks anyway André. khmarbaise, I have no made modifications in java.security.  Should I?